# tex4ht having trouble with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ in mathjax mode

Tags: tex4ht

For some reason, after recent update of texlive, tex4ht in mathjax mode no longer generate valid math for this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   
\[
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0
\]
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

Gives

[image]

But `lualatex foo.tex` gives the correct output

[image]

The HTML generated is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='foo.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='foo.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 9 --><p class='noindent'>\[ \frac {

tial u}{

tial x}=0 \]
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

What happened? Why tex4ht no longer generates correct math? This only happens when using mathjax mode. When not using mathjax mode, the output is correct.

TL 2021 updated about 2 weeks ago on Linux.

ps. [issue added](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?537) to tex4ht

Comment: `\par` from `\partial` has been changed to a blank line which looks.... unfortunate

Comment: @michal.h21 sorry I had a stray mkutils.lua (from I think answering an earlier question here about something) I deleted it....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, that explains it nicely :)

Comment: @Nasser; Good catch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This issue was caused by previous change to the MathJax
processing. The problem was that paragraphs in MathMode produced \par command
instead of blank lines. I've used regex to fix that, but the issue is that it
replaces \partial with two blank lines and string "tial". I've updated the
regex, so it requires some white space after \par, which seems to fix the
issue.

Here is updated version of `mathjax-latex-4ht.4ht`:

```
% mathjax-latex-4ht.sty (2021-12-02-10:19), generated from tex4ht-mathjax.tex
% Copyright 2018-2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-12-02-10:19}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \alteqtoks #1
{
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\detokenize{#1}}
  % % replace < > and & with xml entities
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \x{26} } { &amp; } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \x{3C} } { &lt; } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \x{3E} } { &gt; } \l_tmpa_tl
  % replace \par command with blank lines
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \x{5C}par\b } {\x{A}\x{A}} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl{ \l_tmpa_tl }
  \HCode{\l_tmpb_tl}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewConfigure{MathJaxConfig}{1}

\long\def\AltlMath#1\){\expandafter\alteqtoks{\(#1\)}\)}
\long\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\alteqtoks{\[#1\]}\]}
\long\def\AltMathOne#1${\alteqtoks{\(#1\)}$}
% this seems a bit hacky -- we need to skip some code inserted at the
% beginning of each display math
\long\def\AltlDisplayDollars\fi#1$${\alteqtoks{\[#1\]}$$}

\newcommand\VerbMathToks[2]{%
  \alteqtoks{\begin{#2}
    #1
  \end{#2}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
  \cs_if_exist:cTF{#1}{
    \RenewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{+!b}{%
      \NoFonts\expandafter\VerbMathToks\expandafter{##1}{#1}\EndNoFonts%
    }{}
  }{}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\fixmathjaxtoc#1{\Configure{writetoc}{\def#1{\detokenize{#1}}}}
\def\fixmathjaxsec#1{\def#1{\detokenize{#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\VerbMath{subarray}
\VerbMath{smallmatrix}
\VerbMath{matrix}
\VerbMath{pmatrix}
\VerbMath{bmatrix}
\VerbMath{Bmatrix}
\VerbMath{vmatrix}
\VerbMath{Vmatrix}
\VerbMath{cases}
\VerbMath{subequations}
\VerbMath{aligned}
\VerbMath{alignedat}
\VerbMath{gathered}
\VerbMath{gather}
\VerbMath{gather*}
\VerbMath{alignat}
\VerbMath{alignat*}
\VerbMath{xalignat}
\VerbMath{xalignat*}
\VerbMath{xxalignat}
\VerbMath{align}
\VerbMath{align*}
\VerbMath{flalign}
\VerbMath{flalign*}
\VerbMath{split}
\VerbMath{multline}
\VerbMath{multline*}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{equation*}
\VerbMath{math}
\VerbMath{displaymath}
\VerbMath{eqnarray}
\VerbMath{eqnarray*}
\ConfigureEnv{gather}{}{}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{gather*}{}{}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{multline}{}{}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{multline*}{}{}{}{}
\fixmathjaxsec\left
\fixmathjaxsec\right
\fixmathjaxtoc\int
\fixmathjaxtoc\,
\fixmathjaxtoc\sin
\fixmathjaxtoc\cos
\fixmathjaxtoc\tan
\fixmathjaxtoc\arcsin
\fixmathjaxtoc\arccos
\fixmathjaxtoc\arctan
\fixmathjaxtoc\csc
\fixmathjaxtoc\sec
\fixmathjaxtoc\cot
\fixmathjaxtoc\sinh
\fixmathjaxtoc\cosh
\fixmathjaxtoc\tanh
\fixmathjaxtoc\coth
\fixmathjaxtoc\log
\fixmathjaxtoc\ln
\fixmathjaxtoc\sum
\fixmathjaxtoc\(
\fixmathjaxtoc\)
\fixmathjaxtoc\begin
\fixmathjaxtoc\end
\fixmathjaxtoc\\
\fixmathjaxtoc\exp

}
\endinput
```

The important changes is this:

```
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \x{5C}par\b } {\x{A}\x{A}} \l_tmpa_tl
```

It now tests for white space after `\par`.

Resulting HTML:

[image]

Comment: `\b` (word boundary) might be safer than `\s` so `\par\wibble` still matches.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, I will update it in TL.

Comment: Thanks Michal. Tested on large file completed and see no issues.